# creating temp table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rdbms

i want to create one temp table in procedure and use that table in that procedure only after finishing to execute that 'SP' then automatically delete that table so  how can i do that one?

Comment: check dynamic sql?

Comment: I would recommend that you use global temporary table instead of this approach. The data in the GTT is specific to the session. You will have to create the table only once outside the procedure and use it in the procedure. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables

Comment: What if two sessions want to run the procedure at the same time? Will you have some code to check whether your table exists before attempting to create it? How will you know whether it can be dropped, if other sessions might be using it? Also, do you mean `delete` or `drop`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql

`Execute immediate 'create table...'`

Then you can do your staf

After all all of them in same way you can drop table

`execute immediate 'drop table....`

Answer (score 0):

You can you the dynamic SQL

```
execute immediate 'create table my_table (/* cols here */)';
```

and at the end:

```
execute immediate 'drop table my_table';
```

Also worth mentioning, you can't compile the code while using the temp table directly as table is not present at compile time. You have to use dynamic SQL in order to use it.